# SQL Dynamically Joining Tables on Various Columns

Tags: sql, join, dynamic, logic, case

First time posting!

Have a use case where we want to join some sales data to a master agreement table to determine applicable fee's at a transactional level.

The hard part is that the agreement table has VARIOUS possibilities, and in a worse case scenario at least a "catch all".

We would want to start at the *most granular" level. So the purple line matches on all possible values.
However, a field like the blue sales record does not match on any value to the master except supplier, so in that case it is a catch all.

[image]

I've thought of concat'ing all the rows in the master, but then I'd need to find a way of joining it to sales? a simple concat would not successfully join the blue row example together. So it's like the join would have to dynamically choose which columns to compare.

By chance would any users have some idea's on how to achieve this? 
Thanks!

(Code for tables)

create  TABLE T_TEST_AGREEMENT (
  SUPPLIER VARCHAR(254),
  ITEM VARCHAR(254),
  PROGRAM INT,
  RXDA VARCHAR(254),
  CTRCT INT,
  FEE INT
);

create TABLE T_TEST_AGREEMENT_SALES (
  SUPPLIER VARCHAR(254),
  ITEM VARCHAR(254),
  PROGRAM INT,
  RXDA VARCHAR(254),
  CTRCT INT
);

INSERT INTO T_TEST_AGREEMENT  values
(123, 'A', 60, 'Y', 4, 1),
(123, 'A', 61, 'N', 4, 2),
(123, 'B', 62, null, 5, 3),
(123, 'C', null, 'Y', 6, 4),
(123, null, 63, null, null, 5),
(123, null, null, 'Y', null, 6),
(123, null, null, null, null, 7);

INSERT INTO T_TEST_AGREEMENT_SALES values
(123, 'D', 63, null, null),
(123, 'F', null, null, null),
(123, 'A', 61, 'N', 4),
(123, 'C', null, 'Y', 6);

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  And provide desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select st.*,
       (select m.fee
        from master m
        where m.supplier = st.supplier and
              (m.item is null or m.item = st.item) and
              (m.program is null or m.program = st.program) and
              (m.rxda is null or m.rxda = st.rxda) and
              (m.ctrct is null or m.ctrct = st.ctrct)
        order by ( (case when m.item = st.item then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when m.program = st.program then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when m.rxda = st.rxda then 1 else 0 end) +
                   (case when m.ctrct = st.ctrct then 1 else 0 end) +
                 ) desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as fee               
from sales_transactions st;
```

This uses standard SQL syntax.  It might vary depending on your row.

Comment: This was so close and so cool! I certainly did not think about doing something like this. But when trying this code the "Blue" row from the original example did appear wrong. The fee applied should be the .7 number from master since that was the catch all because no other values match. But the output of the code gave a fee .2, somehow matching it to the second row of the master?

Comment: @JonathanHodge . . . Yes, I see.  It needs to filter only for actual matches and *then* count the matching columns.

Comment: I've been playing with tweaks to the code and have a decent grasp of how it works now. Could you provide an example of how to accomplish what you mentioned? Is it just a case statement to confirm the order by is >0, else pull a subquery against the master for the fee when only the splr exists?

Comment: @JonathanHodge . . . I already fixed the code.  But then broke it again.  And just fixed it.